# How to update a field with a new value in dynamic variable using bash?

Tags: json, bash, shell

How to update a field with a new value in a dynamic variable using bash?

I am storing some curl output in a  variable below is the output response in it.

```
data=$(curl -s --location --request GET "${HOST}/api/v1/envs/projects/${PROJECT_ID}?page=0&pageSize=25" --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer "$token"" | jq -r '.data[]')
echo "$data"

{
  "id": "8aa0809085f46e000185f4c28b7a0b52",
  "createdBy": "8aa0808e82fd01fb0182fd0b05820007",
  "createdDate": "2023-01-27T19:44:28.538+0000",
  "modifiedBy": "8aa0808e82fd01fb0182fd0b05820007",
  "modifiedDate": "2023-01-27T19:45:14.811+0000",
  "version": null,
  "inactive": false,
  "projectId": "8aa0809085f46e000185f4c28b760b51",
  "name": "Master",
  "refId": "Master",
  "description": null,
  "baseUrl": "http://petstore.swagger.io/v1",
}
```

Now I want to update the baseUrl field in that `data` variable dynamically and store that update complete JSON object either in same or different variable to be able use it in a different curl request operation.

How can we do that in  bash scripting?

Comment: *...it in a different curl request operation.* Do you want bash to act as a web server??

Comment: A little bit off topic: In general (99%), `baseUrl=/` is the best choice. With this setting, the website runs with http and https at same time, and also with any domain.

Comment: Try updating the `jq` portion of your command to: `jq -r '.data[] | .baseUrl = "`https://yournewurl.com"'`.   Replace the `https://yournewurl.com` with whatever you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using `jq` to extract part of the data returned from the API. You can extend this `jq` command to modify the `baseURL` field on the fly. The following will update `baseURL` in the first object in the `data` array, then print it out:

```
jq -r '.data[0].baseUrl = "http://example.com" | .data[0]'
```